# jQuery $.each() Acting Asynchronously?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, synchronous

My jQuery function is acting funny and I can't for the life of me figure out why?

```
function getValueFromSettingArray(array,key){
    if(array && array.length > 0){
        console.log("Setting Array Greater Than 0",array);
        $.each(array, function(index,item){
            console.log(index,item);
            if(item.name == key){
                console.log("FOUND",item.value);
                return item.value;
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
}
```

The console sends "FOUND" but the return value is "false", which I have confirmed is coming from the ending return false; The console outputs are even in proper order.

Doing the same thing in a for loop provides the expected results

```
function getValueFromSettingArray(array,key){
    if(array && array.length > 0){
        console.log("Setting Array Greater Than 0",array);
        for(let i=0; i < array.length; i++){
            let item = array[i];
            console.log("item loop " + i, item);
            if(item.name == key){
                console.log("FOUND",item.value);
                return item.value;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Everything I am reading online says $.each() is Synchronous, but it's acting like it's Asynchronous in this manner. I am at a loss, it could be the gaining hours of straight coding, what I am doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Edit: The question was closed as duplicate, but I am not asking how to get the values from an array. I am asking why my result isn't as expected.

@ivor kindly commented pointing out that my inner 'return item.value' was returning the function of my $.each(). This has provided clarity to my issue.

Comment: `return` applies to the enclosing function. The enclosing function in your `$.each` loop is the `function(index,item){ ... }`. Not your `getValueFromSettingArray` function.

Comment: FYI you don't need to use jQuery for this. JavaScript has `Array.prototype.find()` that will return the element that matches a condition.

Comment: @Ivar This makes a lot of sense! Thanks for pointing that out. What would be the proper way to send a result in this context?

Comment: @Barmar As far as I am aware, this is for single dimension arrays. I am working with a multi-dimension array.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that implies a multimensional array. It looks like an array of objects.

Comment: `array` is a 1-d array, `item` is an object.

Comment: @Barmar My apologies, I meant to say key value pairs.

Comment: That's what an object is. The question I linked to shows how to search for a particular value in an array of objects. `return array.find(item => item.name == key)`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for clarifying. I wasn't aware that I could do that! That's very helpful thank you <3